Is there a way to generate with JavaScript an ISO image (Joliet or ISO 9660)?
My purpose is to have an Internet Browser generate a downloadable ISO image (Joliet or ISO 9660) that contains files, starting from file objects (as defined in the Web API).
I am already able to generate a zip file containing files structured in folders, but I have not found libraries or JavaScript projects that allow you to generate ISO images in the browser (for now I am not interested in Node.js solutions).
An ISO image is interesting for distributing data because it can be mounted read-only on the user's client, but I'm also open to other possible alternatives.

Yes, you could definitely write a library that would generate a Blob that adheres to the spec for ISO images, and then createObjectURL on that.
